# Angularjs : TypeError: this.breachDetailsService.getBreachDetails is not a function"

Tags: angularjs

Getting error while injecting service to Component. I have marked the code where i am getting error - "TypeError: this.breachDetailsService.getBreachDetails is not a function"

Component.js class

```
import template from './breach-details.html';
import AutoBoundDependencies from '../../../utils/auto-bound-dependencies';
import breachDetailsService from '../../../rest-services/breach-details.service';

class BreachDetailsComponent extends AutoBoundDependencies {

static get $inject() { return ['breachDetailsService', '$http', '$q']};
constructor(...dependencies) {
    super(dependencies);
}

$onInit(){
    this.detailsView = [];
    this.getBreachDetails().then(detailsView => {
    this.detailsView = detailsView;
    } );

}
```

// getting error in below line

```
  getBreachDetails() {
     this.breachDetailsService.getBreachDetails().then((detailsView) => {
    console.log(detailsView);
    this.detailsView = detailsView;
    });
}
}
export var breachDetailsConfig = {
template: template,
controller: BreachDetailsComponent
};
```

here is the AutoBoundDependencies class

```
export default class AutoBoundDependencies {
constructor(dependencies) {
    this.addDependenciesAsProperties(dependencies);
}

addDependenciesAsProperties(dependencies) {
    let index = 0;

    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.$inject.forEach((value) => {
        this[value] = dependencies[index++];
    })
}
}
```

Comment: I feel like we need to see more relevant code to help you with this. The definition of `breachDetailsService`, particularly. `AutoBoundDependencies` would probably also be helpful.

Comment: `breachDetailsService` is being injected here, so it's not a property of `this`.  try removing `this` and see if you still receive an error.  at least, that's how I read this.  I *think* `AutoBoundDependencies` is supposed to be creating properties for the dependencies, but I can't see how that interacts with `$inject`.